# C# byte array to video

Tags: c#, .net, video, stream

Need to convert byte arrays of images and videos back to its origin. I know how to do it for images as shown below.

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
Bitmap bitMap = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(stream);
```

But I haven't found a good way to do this conversion of byte arrays of videos. Was looking into the System.Drawing.Image namespace, but that namespace is only for images.

Any advice appreciated, thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say "conversion of byte arrays of videos", what are you expecting, and why do you want a Video object, and what would you do with it?

The .NET Framework doesn't have an equivalent of `Bitmap` for video if your intention is to edit it. There are a lot of 3rd party APIs that can do that for you, or if you wanted you could work with something like DirectShow using the DXSlim wrapper around DirectX.

Comment: @vcjones: I'm getting images and videos from a hand held device in the format of byte arrays. And I'm supposed to display them in my application.

Comment: Byte array is NOT a format. What format is the VIDEO in? check DirectShow and see whether you can find a wrapper for .NET.

Comment: http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/ is the "official" .NET wrapper for DirectShow. To do what you're interested in with DirectShow though you would need to create a custom source filter which I don't believe is possible with C# code. You could create the source filter in C++ (it would be a COM object like all DirectShow classes) and send it samples from your C# code with PInvoke or COM interop.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is knowing the format of the video, making sure codecs are available, etc. It's not like a bitmap in which there is a universal standard.

You will probably want to start with the new [Microsoft Media Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms694197%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) if you're trying to do editing or play something with an obscure codec. It's going to be a lot of work. You might do better to use Silverlight here if you're going to be streaming and if you have control over the format.